# CentOS epel repository listed more than once

Tags: centos, yum, repository

So I tried to install `epel` on a CentOS7 server.

I ran `sudo yum install epel-release` as per [these instructions](https://linode.com/docs/databases/redis/install-and-configure-redis-on-centos-7/).

But now whenever I use `yum` for instance with `yum repolist all` I get an error:

> Repository epel is listed more than once in the configuration

`yum` advises to disable the repository with : `yum-config-manager --disable <repoid>`

`/etc/yum.repos.d` has : `epel.repo`, `epel-testing.repo` and `localc7.repo` if that's of any help

Comment: What is the output returned from "yum repolist"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This error usually occurs when you have two repos with the same name. I think you may have named both the epel entries the same.

Try going into `/etc/yum.repos.d`

Look at both the epel files.

Check the name is different.

```
cd /etc/yum.repos.d
cat epel.*
```

Verify that they have different name.

The line you are interested in is:

```
name=SomeName
```

If they share the same name just change it so they are different.

Comment: Maybe testing and non-testing cannot both be enabled?

Answer (score 4):

Another possibility is that you have the same repo defined in different files.  So do:

```
grep epel /etc/yum.repos.d/*
```

.. note the duplicates and rename/comment them out.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the description in `[my_reponame]` is the same as the other file.

I renamed the description as the filename (or other string).

It works for me.